# Flushing python GAE datastore when unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am following [the recommendations on the app engine site for unit testing coding with GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting.html).  I have set the PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy probability to 0% to force the code to account for cases where the data is not yet consistent.  The problem is that in my test suite I want to do some data setup (creating and adding data to the datastore) and need a way to force the datastore to flush all the data into a consistent state before I exercise the code under test.  (ie. make sure that the datastore will return all global entities I have written the next time I do a query).

Is there any way to do this and if not, how are other people setting up data in their tests suites when they are using the consistency models?

Comment: just put 1 in probability to test any write operation is good enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to doing this is noted near the end of the section on HRD testing:

> In the local environment, performing a get() of an Entity that
>   belongs to an entity group with an unapplied write will always make
>   the results of the unapplied write visible to subsequent global
>   queries. In production this is not the case.

Simply add some get operations to your tests to get the appropriate records, and they will show up in future queries.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the best practice for doing this?  I am new to the HRD so although I think I understand what you are saying, I want to make sure I get it correct and completely valid.

Comment: @Allen Just do a `db.get(a_key)` on every entity you stored in the setup routine before running the test proper.

Comment: That worked great.  I wish there was a way to tell it to just flush everything it knows about though.  Thanks for the help.